# Maximum depth of JSONs in a web application in JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, cross-browser

I got strange behaviors (see [Empty ajax request sent by Chrome and Opera (but "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted" with Firefox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882092/empty-ajax-request-sent-by-chrome-and-opera-but-allowed-memory-size-of-1342177)) while using Ajax.

I know that the data I send is composed of big and deep JSONs.

It seems that I shouldn't do this : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279207/how-deeply-can-a-json-object-be-nested

Are there really such limitations in the depth of JSONs ?

If so, how can I get these limits in my PHP server environment and in the browser running my JS client code ?

What are the alternatives to JSON when you want to send data having a recursive structure ?

KR
Zlotz

Comment: Any serialization format is going to have the same problems with large objects and/or deep nesting. The easiest solution is "don't do that", but barring that you'd probably want to look into a parser that doesn't require holding the entire object in memory. Eg: https://packagist.org/packages/salsify/json-streaming-parser

Comment: Sounds good. What about the client side ?

Comment: http://oboejs.com/ may be udeful, I have to  try to integrate all this now.